# Новостная лента как вконтакте

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, ajax, javascript

Друзья, кто подскажет мне, как работает генерация контента в новостной ленте по типу как вконтакте, а именно:

- Открыта страница новостей
- Новые посты всплывают вверху сами, автоматически. Даже если браузер не в фокусе на рабочем столе.

Как это происходит? Натолкните на статью как это реализовали.

Ajax, jQuery ?

Если так, то как, пример хочется взглянуть, а по поисковым запросам не выходит желаемое.

Comment: А что мешает открыть контакт и почитать код?)

Answer (score 1):

У меня такая идея. Каждые n секунд сервер опрашивается Ajax'ом.
а) Тот отвечает, что новых новостей нет и тогда ничего не происходит до следующей проверки.
б) Тот отвечает, что появились новые новости и передает их в теле ответа.

Чтобы лишний раз БД не дергать, можно вместе с INSERT'ом в нужную таблицу, устанавливать особую переменную в сессии равной 1. Проверяющим скриптом надо читать эту переменную из сессии.
Переменная равна 1? Забираем новые записи и обнуляем эту переменную. Иначе отвечаем, что новых записей нет.

Comment: Клиент опрашивает сервер по средствам запущенного скрипта js путём аякс запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Копай в сторону nginx push stream module (или другую фишку push-уведомлений). Работает так:

Пользователь создает свой канал, например, `feed_%id%`. А другие пользователи, при создании записи у себя на стене, отправляют данные через ajax в этот канал. Работает мгновенно и не занимает ресурсов.

Я сам пользую этот модуль и доволен.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется Realtime. Смотрите в сторону: Comet, Websockets, SSE.